# How to change color of <hr> element in XHTML without CSS?

Tags: html, tags, xhtml

W3 Markup Validator shows the following error :

> Line 10, Column 11: there is no attribute "color"  
>   You have used the attribute named above in your document, but
>   the document type you are using does not support that attribute for
>   this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the
>   "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must
>   use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute),
>   or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this
>   is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).
>
> This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in
>   the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no
>   supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error
>   message for further information.
>   How to fix: check the spelling and
>   case of the element and attribute, (Remember XHTML is all lower-case)
>   and/or check that they are both allowed in the chosen document type,
>   and/or use CSS instead of this attribute. If you received this error
>   when using the  element to incorporate flash media in a Web
>   page, see the FAQ item on valid flash.

How do I correct it?

Comment: "How do I correct it?" There is nothing to "correct" here. XHTML does not have a concept of color. If you insist on using presentational attributes, don't use XHTML.

Comment: @BoltClock You suggest that there are HTML versions which do define the `color` attribute on `hr`, but there never were. `color` was always a non-official browser extension, never endorsed by the W3C. The real answer is to use a style.

Comment: @Mr Lister: I never suggested that. I was talking about presentational attributes in general. Of course the real answer in any case is to use a style. The question's premise is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @BoltClock: I'm afraid you did. I read your comment as saying that XHTML *uniquely* doesn't have the concept of colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tl;dr: You can't. Not only does `hr` not have a `color` attribute in XHTML, it never had a color attribute, in any version of HTML! Just use CSS already.

Longer answer:
I don't know why you don't want to use CSS. But if you're really serious about it, here's the solution.

It doesn't matter to the browsers if the code validates or not. If the `color` attribute works, it works, regardless of whether there's a definition for it in the DTD.

So what you're really trying to do is not get it to *work*, but only to get it to *validate*. And, well, that's entirely possible with XHTML. Not with HTML though, mind you; that's what the X in XHTML is for. It's eXtensible!

So just take a XHTML DOCTYPE declaration with a DTD and then append the definition for the color attribute to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"
  [
    <!ATTLIST hr color CDATA #IMPLIED>
  ]
>
<html xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Colored hr without CSS</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <hr color="red"/>
 </body>
</html>
```

There you go, a working *and* validating XHTML document. (Do save it as .xhtml though, not .html)

---

Disclaimer:
One other reason to not use the `color` attribute, aside from the reasons already mentioned, is that it suffers from compatibility issues. For example, if you happen to have a hr with both the `color` attribute and css, the results differ among browsers.

```css
hr {color:blue}
```

```html
<hr color="red">
```

Blue in Firefox, red in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

hr tag doesn't support color attribute , that's why the error occured. Try to use the border property for the hr tag , then it will work. You have to use css for that.

```html
<hr style="border: 1px solid #f00">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the colour of a `<hr>` tag using XHTML alone.

Although some answers have suggested using the `style` attribute, that would be inline CSS and not purely XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use style attribute to change the color of  hr tag.

```
<hr style="border-color: #f00">
```

I think It should work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The **`hr` element supports the CSS `background-color` property**. It also supports the CSS `border`, `margin` and `padding` properties; likely the `position` and associated properties though I'd *highly* recommend considering how off the consideration for using that property is 90% of the time for most elements.

Example:

```
<hr style="background-color: #f00; height: 4px; width: 90%;" />
```